# Image shuffles in list view. when scrolling

Tags: android, listview

What happens is that when scrolling the list, the images that were loaded on each item are shuffled, and the avatar of each item going to the next item ends. I do not know if I'm being clear but I will show with the image
 my custom adapter class

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class CustomListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private ArrayList listData;
    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

    public CustomListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList listData) {
        this.listData = listData;
        layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return listData.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return listData.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row_layout, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.headlineView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
            holder.reporterNameView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.reporter);
            holder.reportedDateView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.date);
            holder.imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.thumbImage);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        NewsItem newsItem = (NewsItem) listData.get(position);
        holder.headlineView.setText(newsItem.getHeadline());
        holder.reporterNameView.setText("By, " + newsItem.getReporterName());
        holder.reportedDateView.setText(newsItem.getDate());
        if (holder.imageView != null) {
            new ImageDownloaderTask(holder.imageView).execute(newsItem.getUrl());
        }
        return convertView;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        TextView headlineView;
        TextView reporterNameView;
        TextView reportedDateView;
        ImageView imageView;
    }
}
```

my news item class

```
public class NewsItem {

    private String headline;
    private String reporterName;
    private String date;
    private String url;

    public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }

    public void setUrl(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }

    public String getHeadline() {
        return headline;
    }

    public void setHeadline(String headline) {
        this.headline = headline;
    }

    public String getReporterName() {
        return reporterName;
    }

    public void setReporterName(String reporterName) {
        this.reporterName = reporterName;
    }

    public String getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(String date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "[ headline=" + headline + ", reporter Name=" + reporterName + " , date=" + date + "]";
    }
}
```

my imageDownloaderTask

```
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import org.apache.http.HttpStatus;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.lang.ref.WeakReference;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

class ImageDownloaderTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
    private final WeakReference<ImageView> imageViewReference;

    public ImageDownloaderTask(ImageView imageView) {
        imageViewReference = new WeakReference<ImageView>(imageView);
    }

    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {
        return downloadBitmap(params[0]);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
        if (isCancelled()) {
            bitmap = null;
        }

        if (imageViewReference != null) {
            ImageView imageView = imageViewReference.get();
            if (imageView != null) {
                if (bitmap != null) {
                    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                } else {
                    Drawable placeholder = imageView.getContext().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.placeholder);
                    imageView.setImageDrawable(placeholder);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    private Bitmap downloadBitmap(String url) {
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        try {
            URL uri = new URL(url);
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) uri.openConnection();
            int statusCode = urlConnection.getResponseCode();
            if (statusCode != HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
                return null;
            }

            InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
            if (inputStream != null) {
                Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
                return bitmap;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            urlConnection.disconnect();
            Log.w("ImageDownloader", "Error downloading image from " + url);
        } finally {
            if (urlConnection != null) {
                urlConnection.disconnect();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Try adding final before ViewHolder declaration like `final ViewHolder viewHolder;`

Comment: no its not working..thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class CustomListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private ArrayList listData;
    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

    public CustomListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList listData) {
        this.listData = listData;
        layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return listData.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return listData.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row_layout, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.headlineView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
            holder.reporterNameView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.reporter);
            holder.reportedDateView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.date);
            holder.imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.thumbImage);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        NewsItem newsItem = (NewsItem) listData.get(position);
        holder.headlineView.setText(newsItem.getHeadline());
        holder.reporterNameView.setText("By, " + newsItem.getReporterName());
        holder.reportedDateView.setText(newsItem.getDate());

        Drawable placeholder = holder.imageView.getContext().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.placeholder;
                holder.imageView.setImageDrawable(placeholder);       

            new ImageDownloaderTask(holder.imageView).execute(newsItem.getUrl());

        return convertView;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        TextView headlineView;
        TextView reporterNameView;
        TextView reportedDateView;
        ImageView imageView;
    }
```

Comment: first set placeholder image to ImageView programatically and then  download image set it again original image

Comment: Yea. its working by this way    Drawable placeholder = holder.imageView.getContext().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.placeholder;
                holder.imageView.setImageDrawable(placeholder);       but when i scrolls, the image get disappears and reappears..thanks

Answer (score 0):

try this. change your getView Like this.

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;
     view=convertView;
    if (convertView == null) {
        view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row_layout, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.headlineView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);
        holder.reporterNameView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.reporter);
        holder.reportedDateView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.date);
        holder.imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.thumbImage);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
    }

    NewsItem newsItem = (NewsItem) listData.get(position);
    holder.headlineView.setText(newsItem.getHeadline());
    holder.reporterNameView.setText("By, " + newsItem.getReporterName());
    holder.reportedDateView.setText(newsItem.getDate());
    if (holder.imageView != null) {
        new ImageDownloaderTask(holder.imageView).execute(newsItem.getUrl());
    }
    return view;
}
```

and declare View view as a class level variable hope it helps thanks. Refer Here
https://androidruler.wordpress.com/2016/02/21/android-custom-listview-example/

Comment: it is not working, getting nullpointer Exception.. Anyway thanks for the respnose..:)

Comment: @KBJ i edited the answer change return view at the end of getview. it wil work